# Word upload function in print/merge

Tags: contacts, printmerge

CiviCRM 5.27.5, Drupal 7.72

I've been attempting to use the print/merge function with no success.  I've tried both .docx and .odt, which the help text says are valid file formats.  However, when I attempt the print/merge, I get the error that my file format is invalid.

Steps to replicate:

- Search for contacts, select a few
- Select Print/Merge Document from the actions menu
- Upload file, click to merge

Is there a particular trick to making this work that I'm missing?

Comment: Does the doc have any complex formatting - tables etc? Does a very simple doc work?

Comment: It is an extremely simple document on purpose - I just wanted to confirm that the process works at all.  I've now tested on a second site (similar Civi versions) and the result was the same.

Comment: Having the same issue.  Hopefully someone can give us some light.

Comment: Same issue with CiviCRM 5.5 on Wordpress and using odt or docx.

Comment: An alternative could be to use CiviOffice: https://docs.civicrm.org/civioffice/en/latest/